Pivot Table: getting corect totals above a threshold
What is the correct way to have pivot table custom formulas that contain constants while still having correct totals & sub-totals?
The custom formula for the "AboveThreshold" column aims at ignoring the first five of each item. It works correctly for the various "items" lines, but the formula is applied the same way for the totals & subtotals. I would like the totals to be recalculated based on the new count for each item, as shown in column H. How can this be achieved?


I'm not sure if you can do it with a pivot table, but you could load your data to Power Pivot, add a calculated column  with something like AboveThreshold = IF([ItemCount] > 5, [Value] - 5, 0) and a measure TotalAboveThreshold = SUMX(     VALUES(Table[Item]),     CALCULATE(SUM(Table[AboveThreshold])) ) (not tested, just a concept idea).

Thanks for thinking about it. I found a workaround, posted below.

Solved  via an intermediate table:

using unique() on both the Group and Item columns
using sumifs() with a criteria on each Group and Item
adding an extra column for subtracting the threshold

And using a pivot table on that intermediate table as a quick way to preserve the original appearance.
